# PHP WITH ORACLE : Querys selects not function for some tables

Tags: php, sql, oracle, codeigniter-2, plsqldeveloper

I am connected to a database using oci8 and codeigniter.
some queries work for some tables and some not.

I have no idea why this should be

**---------  FIRST CASE -------**

**This is my query**

```
public function obtenemos_data3(){
 $conection_remote = $this->load->database('conection_remote', TRUE);
 $sql="select * from ITEM_MASTER WHERE SKU_ID='169989X'";
 $statement=oci_parse($conection_remote->conn_id,$sql);
 oci_execute($statement,OCI_DEFAULT);

 $num_rows = oci_fetch_all($statement, $result);
 echo $num_rows." numero de filas del resultado";

 oci_free_statement($statement);
 oci_close($conection_remote->conn_id);
 return $result;          

}
```

**Result by PHP**

[image]

**Result by program plsqldev**

[image]

**------ SECOND CASE ------**

Just change query

```
    public function obtenemos_data3(){
     $conection_remote = $this->load->database('conection_remote', TRUE);
     $sql="select CASE_NBR from CASE_HDR WHERE CASE_NBR='600008103900000156'";
     $statement=oci_parse($conection_remote->conn_id,$sql);
     oci_execute($statement,OCI_DEFAULT);

     $num_rows = oci_fetch_all($statement, $result);
     echo $num_rows." numero de filas del resultado <br>";

     oci_free_statement($statement);
     oci_close($conection_remote->conn_id);
     return $result;          

    }
```

**Result by php**

[image]

**Result by programa plsqldev**

[image]

I would like to know what might be happening. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Show your code for the second case as well.

Comment: yes it´s correct all. 
but why not return data using php? is the problem.

Comment: Please **post your code** for the second case as well.

Comment: What you are calling "PL/SQL" is just SQL. [PL/SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/plsql/info) is the programming language. Please replace the tag with [SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) if the question is not about procedural code.